# Why my GlideApp doesnt work with a gsReference (Firebase + Kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I want to get an image from Firebase Storage and Im using Glide, and my code look like this:

```
//------- File location
    val gsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://filelocation")

    // Create a reference to a file from a Google Cloud Storage URI
    GlideApp.with(this)
        .load(gsReference)
        .into(imgEvidenceLastReport)
```

The problem I have is when I use the 'gs' reference my image doesnt show, but when I use the https:

```
//------- File location
    val httpsReference  = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("https://filelocation")

    // Create a reference to a file from a Google Cloud Storage URI
    GlideApp.with(this)
        .load(httpsReference)
        .into(imgEvidenceLastReport)
```

I suppose its because I dont have the token on the gs reference but I dont know how to get it, I already have the implementation and the kapt, I create the Module here:

[location of MyAppGlideModule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYHC4.jpg)

And my MyAppGlideModule look like this:

[The code of MyAppGlideModule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SUbe.jpg)

Honestly I just copied and pasted this module

Help :( and thank u :)

Comment: did you manage to use glide ? I am also having problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to figure out this one. In documentation of glide they dont say to implement registerComponents https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html

> You’re not required to implement any of the methods in AppGlideModule for the API to be generated. You can leave the class blank as long as it extends AppGlideModule and is annotated with @GlideModule.

Anyway after I prepared my gradle.build file with proper plugin and dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' // put this next to plugin lines

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.2.0'
```

in order to use FirebaseImageLoader you need to have "firebase-ui-storage" and you have to implement registerComponents in your AppGlideModule as example here https://github.com/laurenskz/pocket-quest/blob/e12253ad867a6c1e3a8d65ff8747979943e87ba7/android/app/src/main/java/nl/pocketquest/pocketquest/game/entities/GlideModule.kt putting down the kotlin code just in case link dies :)

```
import android.content.Context
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.Registry
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
import com.firebase.ui.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import java.io.InputStream

@GlideModule
class AppGlideModule : AppGlideModule(){
    override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        super.registerComponents(context, glide, registry)
        registry.append(StorageReference::class.java, InputStream::class.java, FirebaseImageLoader.Factory())
    }
}
```